# Separation of variables and quantum mechanics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

In the book *Quantum mechanics* by *Eugen Merzbacher*, third edition, at page 462 he claims that this differential equation (for the unknown operator $F_0=F_0(x,y,z)$) can be solved by separation of variables:

$$[F_0,H_0]|1s\rangle=eEz|1s\rangle,$$

where $H_0$ is the non-relativistic *Hamiltonian* for the hydrogen atom:

$$H_0=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{1}{r},$$

$|1s\rangle$ is the fundamental state of the hydrogen atom:

$$|1s\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi a_0^3}}\exp(-r/a_0),$$

$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, $[F_0,H_0]=F_0H_0-H_0F_0$ and the other are constants.

So I tried to use separation of variables $F_0(x,y,z)=X_0(x)Y_0(y)Z_0(z)$, and the equation that I reached is:

$$\frac{X_0Y_0Z_0}{a_0^2r}(r-2a_0)+X_0^{\prime\prime}Y_0Z_0+X_0Y_0^{\prime\prime}Z_0+X_0Y_0Z_0^{\prime\prime}=-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}eEz$$

and I can't proceed from here, it's different from, for example, the wave equation or the heat equation where you can separate the capital functions on each side of the equation. I also tried $F_0(r,z)=R_0(r)Z_0(z)$, but couldn't proceed too.

My questions are: does this equation can really be solved by separation of variables? If yes, what am I doing wrong? If no, what would you suggest me?

EDIT:
The solution given by the author is

$$F_0=-\frac{eEma_0}{\hbar^2}\left( \frac{r}{2}+a_0\right )z$$

One thing that I'm supposing to be true is that, once $F_0$ is a function of
the coordinates only, it commutes with any other function of the coordinates only. With this the potential energy term vanish.

Comment: From Merzbacher's eqn 18.68, we know to use the $F(r,z)=R_0(r) Z_0(z)$ form, but it did not lead me to a general separation of variables.  When I used the form $F(r,z)=R_0(r)z$, the equation separated, but I did not get the correct expression for $R_0(r)$.  Were you able to confirm eqn 18.68 to be a solution of eqn 18.67?

Comment: @Louis, the first time I didn't check. But after you warned me, I checked but wasn't able to confirm that eqn 18.68 is a solution...

Comment: @Louis, I edited the question, corrected some mistakes, and now I was able to confirm that the solution given by the author satisfies the equation.

Comment: How were you able to verify the solution?  Can you post some of your steps?  When I put $F_0$ and $H_0$ into the equation and expand the commutator, the terms with $H_0$ acting on $|1s\rangle$ cancel out and so do the terms with the potential function.  That only leaves $(\nabla^2R_0)Z_0|1s\rangle+R_0(\nabla^2Z_0)|1s\rangle$, and some constants.  I use spherical coordinates to evaluate the first $\nabla^2$ and Cartesian for the second.  So I would like to see your approach.

Comment: @Louis, aren't you forgeting the crossed term $\nabla^2(fg)=f\nabla^2g+g\nabla^2f+\mathbf{2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g}$? And note that you have to take the laplacian of $F_0|1s\rangle$, not of $F_0$ only and then multiply by $|1s\rangle$.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly where I went wrong.  Thanks.